# Authorization header not working for angular 3.9.2

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3, httpmodule

I am using **IONIC 3.9.2**, I am trying to call a **GET** web service with **Authorization** header as Follows:

```
getWebService**(endPoint, parameters,token){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization',token)
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(parameters)
    return this.http.get(BASE_URL+endPoint+jsonData, {headers:headers})
    .map(response => 
    response.json());  
 }
```

When I call this.http.get without **headers.append('Authorization',token)**
It returns response from server

```
{
  "error": true,
  "message": "Access denied. Invalid token key"
}
```

Which is correct, But when I call it with **Authoriztion header** It is giving me following Error
** Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404. **

Tried with :

```
headers.append('Authorization','Basic '+token)
```

too but to no avail. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: Environment Information:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

Comment: First, that's not an Angular question : your error comes from your server, not Angular. Second, the error speaks for itself : you are requesting an endpoint that doesn't exist.

Comment: @trichetriche you don't read the question properly, I explicitly told that if I use Auth Header, it comes with 404, If don't append auth header, it comes with expected response from server.

Comment: I know how to read, thank you. I'm telling you this is a server issue. If you receive a 404 error, you're trying to GET a non-existing endpoint. And just because your unauthorized request has a response doesn't mean your endpoint is existing. It could be your server authorizing the request, then fetching the data. But since you didn't provide neither your server language, nor your list of endpoints, and nor the actual one you're trying to get, that's the only answer I can give you, and so will the others.

Comment: Actually this is working from Native iOS code with AFNetworking
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
I don't know why it isn't working here, 

Here is my URL => http://185.56.85.245/~readytea/test/v1/grades

Comment: It required a token, Here is the temp Authorization header => token => 8689d00c4c96d28b01b94a19422c2343700eecadcb4fdfd0cfeee0ac2109e501

Comment: Because it works in iOS doesn't mean you haven't made a typo in Angular. Instead of commenting with random, unrelated code, and shady URLs, please provide **your server code**, your **list of endpoints**, your **call to the incriminated endpoint**, your **console network request in text**.

Comment: PS: It is working fine through PostMan too,

Comment: Start by using the correct classes too, such as `HttpHeaders` and not `Headers`.

Comment: Alright, that may help, let me check ,

Comment: Which Angular version you are using with Ionic?